How to get selected value to do some stuff such as create a variable using j:set
config.jelly:
<f:entry title="Fruits">
  <f:select field="fruit" />
</f:entry>


Java source code:
public ListBoxModel doFillFruitItems() {
    return new ListBoxModel(
        new ListBoxModel.Option("Apple"),
        new ListBoxModel.Option("Banana")
    );
}

I want to get selected value to do some stuff such as create a variable using j:set such as :
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
    <f:entry title="Fruits">
      <f:select field="fruit" />
    </f:entry>
    <j:set var="tmp" value="${fruit}"/>
    <f:textbox value="${tmp}"/>
</j:jelly>

But tmp variable is always null.
I want to tmp variable is the selected value
Thanks.
